# Use regex to find text NOT between two characters

Tags: regex, string, replace

I have a single string of words, in which each word is separated by a newline character. I've used RegEx replacements to insert '**{**' and '**}**' characters around common prefixes and suffixes. The result looks like this:

```
{con}descens{ion}
lumberjack
tim{ing}
{tox}{icity}
fish
{dis}pel
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how I can perform a RegEx replace on this string that will only match text ***not*** between the '**{**' and '**}**' characters. I have further replacements to make, and each time I do, I'll be placing the '**{**' and '**}**' characters around the matches; I just don't wan't previous replacements (or pieces thereof) to be matched when performing new replacements. I know how to match "*not '{'*", for example, but I don't know how to match "*not between '{' and '}'*"

To put it into perspective, an example next replacement operation here would be to to replace all '**n**' characters with '**7**' characters. In this case, the first line of the string, "{con}descens{ion}", should become "{con}desce{7}s{ion}" and not "{co{7}}desce{7}s{io{7}}"; the other words would remain the same based on these criteria.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could those characters be nested? As in `foo{bar{baz}bam}oof` - and if so, what should happen then? Also, which regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming your curly braces will always be balanced, you can use a *Negative Lookahead* here.

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?![^{]*\})
```

**Note:** This only matches characters of the `A` to `Z` range, if words will include whitespace or you have other characters that need to be allowed or unsure of the type of input, you can use a negated match here.

```
[^}]+(?![^{]*\})
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/tG7kC0)

Comment: Absolutely fabulous. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: This answer fails for anything outside the A-Z range. In other words, it makes unnecessary assumptions about the kind of the input.

Answer (score 5):

In a regular expression engine that supports variable length look-behind, that's easy:

```
(?<=^|\})[^{]+
```

In one that does not support look-behind (or fixed-length look-behind only) it's a little different:

```
(^|})([^{])
```

Here you must use both groups: group 1 contains nothing or a `}`, depending on the position of the match, group 2 contains the actual match. If you make replacements, make sure you re-insert the contents of group 1.

*Note that this answer does not not work for nested constructs.*