# RegEx to find all occurrences of a character not between two other characters

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm looking for a regex (that I can implement in Javascript, so no lookbehinds) which will match all occurrences of a character, as long as it doesn't appear between two other characters. For example, I want to match all hyphens as long as they are not between plus signs.

```
----- // should match.
+---+ // should not match
---+---+--- // should only match the first 3 and last 3 characters.
```

I've tried adapting the method used in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948557/use-regex-to-find-text-not-between-two-characters) like so:

```
[-]+(?![^+]*\+)+
```

But it is not matching as desired. Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. Looking specifically for a **REGEX** solution. I realize this may not be the optimal solution but I'm specifically trying to improve my knowledge of regex.

Comment: Why does it *have* to be regex? This is trivial to implement with string methods.

Comment: This is an XY problem. Please explain what you are doing in real life.

Comment: I'm not allowed to ask XY questions on SO?

Comment: I think you need to lookup what an XY problem is :)

Comment: You can ask, we can close as 'unclear what your asking'. If you want unpaid help from strangers on the internet, you gotta play by the rules.

Comment: @JaredSmith it doesn't have to be RegEx, but the fact that I can't figure it out with a RegEx means there's a learning opportunity here...

Comment: `/(^-+|-+$|(?!.*\+)-+)/g`

Comment: In that case to avoid getting hammered I would state in the question something to the effect of "I realize regex might not be the optimal solution but I'd like to know *how* it could be achieved with regex".

Comment: Ok, I can edit.

Comment: Maybe you can use [The Trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick): [`\+-+\+|(-+)`](https://regex101.com/r/rg5r7P/1) (:

Comment: What are you going to do with the matches? Collect and display? Replace? bobblebubble suggests the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
(?:^-+|-+$)
```

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/524iej/1

Answer (score 1):

If the delimiters (`+` in your case) always come in pairs, you could use this:

```js
var str = 'a-b-+-c-+-d-e'; // delimter is +
matches = str.match(/-(?=([^+]*\+[^+]*\+)*[^+]*$)/g, '');
console.log(matches); // 4 matches of `-`
```

This matches every hyphen that has an even number of pluses following it (could be zero).

Answer (score 0):

You can use use `.replace` to remove all text between 2 `+`s:

```
str = str.replace(/\+-*\+/g, '');
```

**Example:**

```
var str = '---+---+---';
str = str.replace(/\+-*\+/g, '');
//=> ------
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm asking how to match the characters NOT between the hyphens.

Comment: I think you're asking to match not between plus sign right? Using this `.replace` we're removing everything between `+`s hence leaving only part that is outside 2 `+` signs