# Regex to get character not between two other characters

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

How would one use Regex to get a character/word that is not between two other characters/words?

For example, in:

`hello world [hello hello] world hello [world hello world hello] world hello [hello] hello`

It would select:

**hello** world [hello hello] world **hello** [world hello world hello] world **hello** [hello] **hello**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948557/use-regex-to-find-text-not-between-two-characters) gets text, not between two characters (`(?<=^|\])[^[]+`), which is close, all one needs to do on top of that is select specific words from that.

Comment: You could do it the other way around with a capturing group `\[[^][]*]|\b(hello)\b` https://regex101.com/r/3BXpYf/1 See https://ideone.com/PP0QM5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the opposite approach by selecting what you don't want, which is from an opening till closing square bracket. Then use an alternation using `|` and capture what you want to keep.

Using for exampole [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) you get the values of the capturing groups, and then you can filter out the empty strings.

```
\[[^][]*]|\b(hello)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3BXpYf/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/PP0QM5)

Example code

```
import re
 
regex = r"\[[^][]*]|\b(hello)\b"
 
test_str = ("hello world [hello hello] world hello [world hello world hello] world hello [hello] hello")
 
print(list(filter(None, re.findall(regex, test_str))))
```

Output

```
['hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'hello']
```

Comment: If I wanted to change this to match the dollar sign character, what would I do? I tried `\[[^][]*]|\b(\$)\b` but it's only matching things inside brackets.

Comment: @user-124812948 In that case you can omit the word boundaries `\[[^][]*]|(\$)` https://regex101.com/r/21CIVB/1

Comment: How would I use `re.sub` with this? It seems to replacing things inside of brackets.

Comment: @user-124812948 You could make use of a callback using a lambda. If group 1, then return the replacement. Else return the match. See https://ideone.com/4vX8sh

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for everything!

Answer (score 0):

Use PyPi regex:

```
import regex
text='hello world [hello hello] world hello [world hello world hello] world hello [hello] hello'
print( regex.sub(r'\[[^][]*](*SKIP)(?!)|\b(hello)\b', r'++\1++', text) )
```

[Code demo](http://oRKEoNT21gqsktaLEVj0jNScnX6E8vygnRSEawgGTsVAxiFA0MgeJjaYKKgam1LkKijLzSjQgtukVlyZpFKnHREfHxUbHasVqaAV7ewZoatgratbEJGmAdWjGJKnrKBSpa2vHGGprA5kgF2oqaP7)

Output:

```
++hello++ world [hello hello] world ++hello++ [world hello world hello] world ++hello++ 
[hello] ++hello++
```

`\[[^][]*](*SKIP)(?!)|\b(hello)\` expression matches strings between square brackets and these matches are dropped, `hello` is matched within word boundaries and replaced eventually with `regex.sub`.